# Invalid Host Header cuando ngrok intenta conectar al dev server

Tags: web

Existe una herramienta llamada **ngrok** (http://ngrok.io) que básicamente hace que tu localhost pueda ser visualizado desde cualquier lado gracias a la magia de internet. Es de aquellas herramientas que te van a hacer la vida más fácil como desarrollador.

Una vez que descargué la app y la ejecuté, me dio el enlace para visualizar, hasta aquí todo excelente, voy al iPad para probar y...

```
Invalid Host Header
```

Intenté abrir cualquier otra página que tengo en localhost y todas me daban lo mismo, ¿qué hacemos? ¿lloramos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero lo primero, vamo a calmarno. Ahora bien, considerando que el problema dice:

> Invalid Host Header

Tenemos la idea que la solución debe/puede estar relacionada al **host header** por lo tanto, en la documentación probablemente exista algo así.

Link de la documentación: https://ngrok.com/docs#host-header

**Texto original:**

### Rewriting the Host header

When forwarding to a local port, ngrok does not modify the tunneled HTTP requests at all, they are copied to your server byte-for-byte as they are received. Some application servers like WAMP, MAMP and pow use the Host header for determining which development site to display. For this reason, ngrok can rewrite your requests with a modified Host header. Use the -host-header switch to rewrite incoming HTTP requests.

If rewrite is specified, the Host header will be rewritten to match the hostname portion of the forwarding address. Any other value will cause the Host header to be rewritten to that value.

**Traducido al buen español:**

### Reescribir el encabezado del Host

Cuando se reenvía a un puerto local, ngrok no modifica en absoluto las peticiones HTTP tunelizadas, sino que las copia a su servidor byte por byte a medida que se reciben. Algunos servidores de aplicaciones como WAMP, MAMP y pow utilizan la cabecera Host para determinar qué sitio de desarrollo mostrar. Por esta razón, ngrok puede reescribir sus peticiones con una cabecera de Host modificada. Utilice el parámetro -host-header para reescribir las peticiones HTTP entrantes.

Si se especifica reescribir, el encabezado del host se reescribirá para que coincida con la parte del nombre del host de la dirección de reenvío. Cualquier otro valor hará que el encabezado del Host sea reescrito a ese valor.

**Solución**

Hay que definir el encabezado del host, en este caso es localhost:8080, lo que tenemos que aplicar el siguiente comando:

```
ngrok http 8080 -host-header="localhost:8080"
```

Listo, funcionó y todos felices. A seguir desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!