# ¿Cómo puedo configurar localhost para mi celular?

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

alguien sabe la ultima configuración que se puede hacer para poder ver m wampserver en mi celular? lo que sucede es que quiero ir probando como se vería mi aplicación php en dispositivos móviles.

Comment: Tendrías que tener tanto tu ordenador como tu móvil en la misma red. Luego, sabiendo la IPv4 del ordenador que mantiene el WAMP, donde antes ponías `localhost/miweb/mivista.html` tendrías que sustituir "localhost" por la IPv4 para apuntar correctamente hacia él.

Comment: Conectas tu celular a la red local donde está el servidor y lo consumes por la IP del mismo (192.168...).

Comment: Aportando a los comentarios debes deshabilitar el firewall de windows para acceder al contenido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hay una forma de hacerlo y es con "**ngrok**", es un pequeño software que nos ayuda a visualizar lo que tengamos en nuestro "**localhost**" desde cualquier dispositivo que esté en nuestra red.

Descárgalo desde aquí: https://ngrok.com/download

El archivo pesa 25MB aprox. Una vez descargado, lo descomprimes y tendrás "**ngrok.exe**".

Lo ejecutamos y tendremos algo como esto:
[image: ngrok-terminal]

Luego escribimos el siguiente comando: `ngrok http 80`

[image: ngrok-terminal-runing]

Ejecutamos dicho comando y obtendremos algo similar:

Elige una de las URL's para ingresar desde el navegador del dispositivo que desees y que estén en la misma red para apreciar tus proyectos en ellos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he tratado de explicar paso a paso, pero en realidad es muy rápido su uso y, hasta el momento, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Excelente bro gracias

Comment: De nada, Jesu :D.

Answer (score 1):

Para efectos prácticos, utiliza esta herramienta: https://ngrok.com/ básicamente hace que tu localhost pueda ser visualizado desde cualquier lado gracias a la magia de internet. Es de aquellas herramientas que te van a hacer la vida más fácil como desarrollador.

Si por algún motivo, te da un error del tipo `Invalid Host Header` la respuesta la encuentras aquí: [Invalid Host Header cuando ngrok intenta conectar al dev server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245542/822)

Comment: Gracias bro esa herramienta me ayudó

Comment: dale hermano, me alegra saber que te fue de utilidad, sigue desarrollando, elevando ese cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!! éxitos :D

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenos días lo que tendías que hacer para poder visualizar tu sistema WEB en tu dispositivo móvil es:

1. Sustituir tu localhost por la IP de tu computadora ejemplo yo en CodeIgniter tengo mi base_url donde es http://localhost/Controlador/ y únicamente cambio el localhost por x.x.x.x haciendo referencia a tu IP.
2. Finalmente escribe correctamente la ruta de tu pagina en el navegador por ejemplo http://x.x.x.x/Controlador/ y listo.

Espero que te pueda funcionar.

Saludos.