# Permitir acceso a servidor IIS en una LAN

Tags: iis

Hola todos espero por favor me puedan ayudar.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil que requiere conectarse a la API que se encuentra alojada en un servidor, estoy usando IIS. Cuando genero las pruebas dentro del equipo, me enlaza de forma correcta, pero cuando intento acceder desde el celular no me permite. Intento ingresar a la dirección IP de ese servidor desde otro dispositivo conectado a la red, pero no obtengo respuesta.

No sé si necesito instalar o configurar algo adicional en el IIS, agradezco por favor me puedan ayudar, si necesitan más información con mucho gusto se las brindo.

Comment: Eso es configuración de DNS a nivel de red, y aquí las preguntas/respuestas van más orientadas hacia desarrollo. Aunque existen preguntas de redes que no deberían estar, la comunidad lo ha permitido, por otro lado, revisa si están en la misma red.

Comment: Lo siento, de igual forma gracias por tu comentario. Pero sí, ambos dispositivos se encuentran en la misma red

Comment: Descuida, este es un mejor sitio para este tipo de preguntas https://serverfault.com/ Si están en la misma red, en teoría deberías poder acceder al IIS. Si hay problemas con eso, lo más probable es que haga falta agregar configurar el DNS

Comment: No conocía ese sitio, muchas gracias. ¿Tendría que configurar el DNS en el equipo donde se encuentra solamente?

Comment: Estamos para servir hermano. Sí, normalmente el DNS de la empresa tiene la IP de la dirección del IIS. Las computadoras que tienen el DNS resuelven las direcciones web a IPs.

Comment: Pero si requiero la conexión en una App Movil?

Comment: Igual, en configuraciones de red del móvil se coloca el DNS y demás detalles. Si el IIS es intranet, podrías usar `ngrok` para comprobar desde la máquina de desarrollo a tu móvil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245542/822

Comment: Perfecto, lo revisaré y comento el resultado. Muchas gracias

Comment: No tuve la necesidad de revisar el DNS. Te comento, con un compañero revisamos la situación e intentamos hacer PING a la IP del servidor desde otro PC, obtuvimos respuesta, así que revisamos la configuración del Firewall y generamos una nueva regla de entrada que habilitara el puerto que estaba usando el servidor. Una vez eso, logramos establecer la conexión. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución y se las comparto por si a alguien le llega a servir esta información,

- Es necesario habilitar el puerto el cual estás usando en tu servidor en el firewall
- Creas una regla de entrada TCP para habilitar el puerto que estés usando.

Comment: Saludos no olvides que si es la solución a tu duda la puedes marcar mas adelante como aceptada, +1

Comment: en 24 horas recuerda marcar como aceptada :D