# Como puedo ver mi proyecto laravel + vue 3 en una red local

Tags: laravel, vue3

alguien sabe como puedo ver mi proyecto en laravel + vue 3 mediante otro dispositivo en la misma red local?
ejecute este comando
`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

me devuelve una pagina en blanco

Comment: Revisa `NgRok`, https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245542/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es abrir un terminal y ejecutar:  `npm run dev` y en otro terminal ejecutas `php artisan serve`.

Comment: amen, en la pc donde estoy construyendo el proyecto puedo levantar/ver sin problemas mis paginas laravel+vue, el problema esta cuando intento acceder desde otro dispositivo, me devuelve solo pagina en blanco. (Se que se conecta correctamente porque en la consola me aparecen las solicitudes de icon) .. gracias de antemano

Comment: Has un ipconfig en la pc. Luego revisa cual es la IP que estás usando. Y en el otro equipo (que se supone que está conectado a la misma red) pones en la URL la IP de tu máquina: el puerto que te da laravel

Comment: Logro conectarme correctamente desde el dispositivo (Celular), al dispositivo con el proyecto, el problema es que me devuelve la pagina en blanco.